# IE 11 won't show the correct width of my table HTML columns

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

It works perfectly in Chrome or FireFox, it's basic css coding but here :

```
<td
    style="
        text-align: right;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        max-width: 60px;
        width:60px;
    "
>
    @Model.Item1
</td>
```

I've put `max-width` AND `width` just to be sure...

Seem like IE has some reasons to ignore them and puts the default width... which is about 200px. FAR from being 60px...

Any idea ?

**Entire table :**

```
<table style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; table-layout:fixed; ">
    <tr >
        <th rowspan="2"  style="">
            Service de garde

        </th>
        <th colspan="2" style="" >
            Paie
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" style="">
            Avant Garde
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" style=" width:180px;">
            Ratio
        </th>
    </tr>


    <tr >
        <th style="text-align: center ; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid ">
            Dépenses
            Salaires

        </th>
        <th style=" ">
            Heures
            travaillées
        </th>
        <th style="">
            Heures
            présences
        </th>
        <th style="">
            Frais facturés
        </th>
        <th style="max-width: 120px; width:120px; ">
            Avec
            Responsable
        </th>
        <th style="max-width: 60px; width:60px;" >
            Sans
            Responsable
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="@Url.Action("ParService","Tableaux", new {   })">Tous les services de garde</a></td>
        <td style=""> @Model.depensesSalaires </td>
        <td style=""> @Model.hTravaille </td>
        <td style=""> @Model.hPresence </td>
        <td style=""> @Model.fraisFacture </td>
        <td style="max-width: 120px; width:120px;" > @Model.avecResp </td>
        <td style="max-width: 60px; width:60px;"> @Model.sansResp </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Table cells (`display: table-cell;`) has special rules for sizing compared to "normal" (`display: block;`) elements. If you want to ensure a table column width then use `table-layout: fixed;` and set an explicit width on the first row's cell in the desired column.

Comment: You've only provided HTML for a single table cell. Please post the **rendered HTML** of the entire table, if possible, or at least a few rows (including the `<thead>` if applicable).

Comment: @Dai thanks for your first edit, i edited again : here is the table, I removed most useless styles (color and border) so it will be easier to get to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem today. In the content folder, there is a file named `Site.css`.

In this file, there were :

```
td,th
{
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

I removed it and now it works.

When using IE11, this file's css takes priority over the inline style.

I don't know why though. Personally i think inline style should always take priority over anything else.